# Examining stationarity, mean and variance of time series

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, stationarity, unit-root

[image: Question:]

Hi guys, I encounter this question for a Business Forecasting module and I am very confused by it. Firstly, this looks like an autoregressive model of order 1. From the looks of it, the φ coefficient is 1. Doesn't this mean that the time series cannot be stationary and the ACF will be 1 at all lags?

Also, how can we find mean and variance? These are the formulas I was given:
[image]

But if φ = 1, then the denominator for both formulas would be 0, and there would be no mean or variance. How exactly do I solve this question? Does this have something to do with inverting the AR(1) process into a MA(infinite) process?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.